# Regex to split string based on html tags

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a string where i want to split it based on the tags

Sample string:

```
var str = '<p>Hi my name is XXX</p>\n\n<p>Iam going to london</p></p>'
```

I want to split the string based on their tags

Expected result:

```
splitString = ['<p>Hi my name is XXX</p>', '<p>Iam going to london</p>'];
```

What regex should be used to get the expected result, thanks in advance!

Comment: You just killed an unicorn while trying to parse html with regex.

Comment: Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/4265352) first.

Comment: This is called parsing. Don't use Regular Expressions for parsing HTML documents. Use a DOM parser instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An approach without a regular expression (see the comments for the "why").

- Create a temporary container ([`.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement))
- Insert the markup and let the browser handle the parsing and fixing of maybe invalid markup ([`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML))
- Get the nodes you want ([`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll))
- Convert the HTMLCollection into an actual array for easier handling ([`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from))
- Get the [`.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) ([`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

```js
function getParagraphs(htmlString) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", htmlString);
  
  return Array.from(div.querySelectorAll("p"))
              .filter(p => p.textContent !== "") // because of the lonely </p> at the end - optional
              .map(p => p.outerHTML);
}

const str = '<p>Hi my name is XXX</p>\n\n<p>Iam going to london</p></p>';
console.log(getParagraphs(str));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = '<p>Hi my name is XXX</p>\n\n<p>Iam going to london</p></p>'
console.log( str.match(/<p>([^\<]*?)<\/p>/g) );
```

see: https://regex101.com/r/mtPZVg/1